# Retrieving my google contacts

Tags: google-account, google-contacts, services, compass, cell-broadcast

My smart phone kept turning off and wouldn't power back up or stay on long enough to use it much unless I had it plugged into an electrical outlet; so I cancelled my cell phone service but continued using it too look up my contacts so I could call them on a landline. Is there a way I can retrieve my cell phone contacts saved on google by using my computer?

Comment: Did you synchronize them with Google? As in that case, you can simply log in to Gmail using your web browser and export them from there.

Answer (score 1):

As your contacts are synchronized with your Google account, you can:

1. get them in [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com) or
2. use [an export tool](http://www.exportmycontacts.com/) to select just the contacts you want and export them to a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to sign into your Google account on your device and if you had your account settings to automatically back up your information such as contacts, photos etc they should come right up on any device you log into.